# Vba find & replace a number by a macro.Excel

Tags: vba, excel

I'm making an heuristic analyse and i have the following problem:

I want to find in column D numbers that match with column J and replace them by a "0". You can see what I'm trying to do on this image: http://imageshack.us/f/96/heuristic.jpg/

Some parts of the code:

```
   Dim i,j As Integer
   Dim temp As String
   Dim x As Integer
   Dim d As String

   i = Application.CountA(Range("E:E")) + 10
   'number of cell with values
   j = Application.CountA(Range("J:J")) + 10
   For j = 11 To j
        temp = Range("J" & j).Value
          For i = 11 To i
           d = Range("D" & i).Value
           *
           Next
  Next
```

At the `*` lies the problem, I can't figure out how to pass over the comma `","` in column D, and store the data. I want to compare the temp with value on `"d"`, but `"d"`. Can I have multiple numbers on the same cell, like `"3,2,1"`, and if there is any match like `temp = 3, then d= "0,2,1"`.

English is not my native language so I hope you can understand what I want.

Comment: What have you tried? Show your existing code if you have any: if not then maybe try writing some first.  And please format your sample data so it's useful - use the "code" button.

Comment: If u want i cand send you my macro..

Comment: @Delpi10, please edit your post and add your code there so we can look at it.

Comment: @PowerUser i want to edit my post but i'm new hear, my code is to big and i'm afraid that you wont understand what i'm trying to do.

Comment: You don't need to include the entire code set, just the parts that relate to your question.  Without it, we don't know your experience level with VBA or how advanced your project is.

Comment: Also, an example might help us understand your question better.

Comment: @Poweruser this is my problem http://imageshack.us/f/96/heuristic.jpg/

Comment: I hope u can understand, i want fin in column D numbers that match i with column J and replace them by a 0.

Answer (score 1):

There's no need for VBA. Standard Excel functions will work:

1. Make a new column somewhere near column D.
2. In your new column, use this formula `=IF(ISERROR(VLOOKUP(D11,J:J,1,FALSE)),D11,0)`. This formula looks up the value of D11 in column J. If a match is found, 0 is returned. Otherwise, D11 is returned.
3. If you want, you can hide column D to avoid confusion.

If you have to do this multiple times, you may want to have an unformatted 'raw data' tab and a clean 'display tab'. Does that help?

Comment: Hi thanks for your help,but what i want its to change the number that match, not to return a 0, because in column D it can have more than one number. The problem is that I do not know how to compare numbers that are separated by commas. For example in column D i have "3,4,5" and in column "J"  i  have the 5, I want column D becomes "3,4,0". But so comes to my mind using arrays, but then i do not know what will be the position in the column, nor the size of the array because column D may have several numbers.

Comment: In that case, I think your biggest problem is storing multiple distinct values in a single cell. This is not a good practice for storing data and creates problems like the one you are asking here.  I suggest rebuilding your Excel table so that there is only 1 value in each cell (maybe use 4 columns for `precedencias`?)