# Vba how to compare 2 column

Tags: string, excel, replace, comparison, vba

I'm making an heuristic analyse and i have the fallowing problem : I want to find in column D numbers that match with column J and replace them by a "0". You can see what I'm trying to do on this image : 
[image]

Problem : Column D have multiples values per cell and column J have one value per cell.
some part of the code:

```
 Dim i,j As Integer 
 Dim temp As String
 Dim x As Integer
 Dim d As String

i = Application.CountA(Range("E:E")) + 10
'number of cell with values
j = Application.CountA(Range("J:J")) + 10
For j = 11 To j
     temp = Range("J" & j).Value
       For i = 11 To i
        d = Range("D" & i).Value

         *For x = LBound(vec) To UBound(vec)

           If vec(x) = temp Then
            vec(x) = 0
            Range("D" & i).Value = vec(x)
            End If

            Next            


        Next
Next
```

*-> Here it is the problem, i cant figured out how to pass over the coma "," in column D,and store the data. I want to compare the temp with value on "d", but "d" can i have multiple numbers on the same cell, like " 3, 2, 1", and if there is any match like temp = 3, then d= "0,2,1".

English is not my native language so i hope you can understand what i want.

Thanks!

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16549546/vba-find-replace-a-number-by-a-macro-excel

Answer (score 1):

I think your almost there you just need to split up each cell and then search then recreate and replace the string in the cell. **Please note I've not tested this.**

```
 Dim i,j As Integer 
 Dim temp As String
 Dim x As Integer
 Dim d As String

i = Application.CountA(Range("E:E")) + 10
'number of cell with values
j = Application.CountA(Range("J:J")) + 10
For j = 11 To j
     temp = Range("J" & j).Value
       For i = 11 To i
        d = Range("D" & i).Value
        Vec = split(d, ",") 'split the cell
        d = "" 'clear the string

         For x = LBound(vec) To UBound(vec)

           If vec(x) = temp Then
            vec(x) = 0
           End If
           d = d & vec(x) & "," 'recreate the string

         Next            

         Range("D" & i).Value = left(d, len(d) - 1) 'save the string without the last ,

     Next
Next
```

Comment: I don't see why. I'll have to test and get back to you.

Answer (score 0):

you can do this with the below formula - no need for VBA

1. Make a new column somewhere near column D.
2. In your new column, use this FIND and Substitute formula:

   ```
   =IF(NOT(ISERROR(FIND(J:J,D:D))),SUBSTITUTE(D:D,J:J,"0"),D:D)
   ```

This formula looks for the value in column J within the cells in column D.
If a match is found, 0 is substituted for the found number. Otherwise, column D is returned.

- If you want, you can hide column D to avoid confusion.

in **VBA** you have a string function called *Split(vString, delimiter)* that will split a string into tokens using the specified delimiter. See

- [MSDN Library: VB Split Function](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa263365%28v=vs.60%29.aspx)

examples:

- [Mr Spreadsheet John Walkenbach: Split Function examples](http://spreadsheetpage.com/index.php/tip/the_versatile_split_function/)
- [VB-Helper](http://www.vb-helper.com/howto_multiline_split.html)

Comment: Hey thanks for your answer ! I already tried the split function, but the problem using that function is how can you pass the values again to column D with "," ?Because when you split the numbers when you pass the data(array) to the column it will be like this "023" , and i want "0,2,3".

Comment: so you can loop through the array, concatenating each number with an comma, building your string. **alternatively, you can use the formula**